# Increase font size in browser resize

Tags: css

Is there a way to set `font-size` **dynamically change** on browser resize with `css`?

I have breakpoints setted with media queries. At the first breakpoint, font size is, lets say `1em`. On the other breakpoint, text enlarges to `2em`.

Font resize only happens on the breakpoint. I'm loking for the effect you achieve when you set a cointainer width to percentages (it resizes automatically when you resize the browser.)

Is there a way to make the text enlarge from one breakpoint to the other dynamically **without** using javascript?

Comment: You mean that the text should animate between two states?

Comment: @David Yes. It should increase from 1em to 2em in beetweetn the breakpoints. Not suddenly. Is a bit confusing, didn't know how to explain the need very well

Comment: I made some edits and added another mediaqueries example, that’s the best I can do in pure CSS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the font size onresize depending on the window size, you need to bind a javascript handler to the window resize event. If you just want to animate between two states, you can use CSS3 animations, f.ex:

```
-webkit-transition:font-size 1s ease-out;
```

http://jsbin.com/uyitut/1

This example uses a button for trigger just to demo the transition, but you could add multiple media queries instead. Here is a rather awkward example of one mq per 100px: http://jsbin.com/uyitut/5 but it kinda works.

Comment: always include all vendor prefixes, including non-vendor prefix

Comment: How do you know the OP isn’t targeting webkit only?

Comment: I use ff and others might too, SO is for all, btw the above will not work while accessing in Responsive layouts. Transitions do not happen while moving from one media query to another. The Question is how to show transition effect when you resize the browser.

Comment: By **all** you mean lynx browsers and Netscape 4 too? I think the OP got the point, no need to clutter the answer with obvious stuff. Transitions do happen in media queries of course: http://jsbin.com/uyitut/4 although I agree that this does not accomplish exactly what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved, see the demo [CSS transitions & media queries](http://static.elliotjaystocks.com/css-transitions-media-queries/demo2.html) and the article [Adding the transitions](http://elliotjaystocks.com/blog/css-transitions-media-queries/)